# Can't access returned json data from handsontable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, handsontable

I have the following data being sent back to my Node/Express/Body-parser backend from a HandsOnTable.

```
[["Bob",null,"PhD",null],["Jane",null,"Masters",null],["Stew",null,"Degree",null]]
```

I'd like to be able to access each record (row) of data e.g. Bob, null, "PhD", null. This would give me my data to write out a document in Node.

When I do a `console.log(req.body.table)` I get all of the data above - if I do a `console.log(req.body.table[0])` I only get a single '['.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.body.table` is a string, that's why you get the first character only when doing `req.body.table[0]`.

Parse it first

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(req.body.table);

var bob = parsed[0];
```

or if you're only consuming JSON, you can set Node Bodyparser to do it for you

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```